# iPad - Setup both PPTP and L2TP VPNs - blocked by firewall - can I use the 'Proxy' settings to evade?

Tags: ipad, vpn, settings, proxy

I'm using the [VPN Express](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=vpn+express&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEkQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fus%2Fapp%2Fvpn-express-best-mobile-vpn%2Fid375584677%3Fmt%3D8&ei=CyqlUKnaO5OL0QHuvoHgDA&usg=AFQjCNG6HvjDmFQKdvt4WemhhD4ZvmmFwQ&sig2=OfEa5uR9lsSiOEbvMR5PNw) app to setup PPTP and L2TP connections. It automatically sets the VPN profiles up successfully for me. When I try to connect, get error messages telling me that the server did not respond.

I'm fairly certain that the network I am using blocks VPN connections somehow. Is there any way I can use the 'Proxy' settings at the bottom of a VPN connection configuration window to avoid this? Can someone just briefly tell me what that's supposed to do? I'm guessing the main thing I need to do is use an alternate port, and with the Manual Proxy settings it appears I can do that. I just don't know what I should use for a server and authentication.

Comment: Have you determined if your network is simply blocking the common ports that PPTP/l2TP use? If so, you would simply set up your servers to listen on non-standard ports and configure your iPad to match. You might need to use a common port like 80 or see what ports are open first. If the network is actually sniffing packets and detecting your VPN - you'll need to do something like set up a ssh tunnel or find another network / get them to poke a hole in it by human engineering methods.

Comment: I'm just assuming that they're blocking the ports. Is there any way for me to check? Also, the VPN server is set up through that app, so I don't know if there's any way to change listening ports.